# How would I redirect urls in this way?

Tags: url, redirect

So, this is a little bet more of a high level question. I'm not necessarilly looking for specifics, but more of the general tools and technologies I need to use. I'm really new to website hosting and development.

I want to redirect a domain, say something.com to something.squarespace.com. How would I go about doing this so that the following occurs:

1. The address bar never has the url something.squarespace.com in it.
2. When a user clicks a link on the site that goes to a local page on something.squarespace.com (so say, something.squarespace.com/page1), the address bar says something.com/page1.
3. something.com currently is pointing to a shared hosting apache webserver. I would like to be able to maintain access to files and email on that server. If I couldn't get the files, that's fine. But the email is crucial.

I know this is a lot to ask - but if anyone can help me out with some advice on this I'll be very thankful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at URL rewriting concept. that's where you can achieve what you're asking in 1 at 2. As for no 3, I couldn't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: For three, I mean that it is an add on domain on my webserver. I added it using cpanel. I'd like to be able to access the files on my server that fall under "something.com" and the email I have setup thru that domain on my webserver